# viewChild is showing undefined in console

Tags: javascript, html, angular

//This is my html file ,Here i declared "**#bodyText**" and **#truncated** to access the element in the component but showing **undefined** in onInit() hook, however it is working fine in **ngAfterView**() component.

```
<div class="note-card-content">

    <h1 class="note-card-title">{{title}}</h1>

    <div #bodyText class="note-card-body">
        <p>{{body}}</p>

        <div #truncator class="fade-out-truncation"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="x-button"></div>
```

// This is the component

> ```
> import { Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, Renderer2, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
>
> @Component({
>   selector: 'app-note-card',
>   templateUrl: './note-card.component.html',
>   styleUrls: ['./note-card.component.scss']
> })
>
> export class NoteCardComponent implements OnInit {
>
> //These two elements are showing undefined when I print on console
>
>   @ViewChild('truncator') truncator:ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
>   @ViewChild('bodyText') bodyText:ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
>
>   @Input() title:string;
>   @Input() body:string
>
>
>   constructor(private renderer:Renderer2) { }
>
>   ngOnInit(): void {
>
>     console.log(this.truncator)
>     // Work out if there is a text overflow and if so,then hide
>     let style = window.getComputedStyle(this.bodyText.nativeElement,null);
>
>     let viewableHeight = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("height"),10)
>
>     if(this.bodyText.nativeElement.scrollHeight > viewableHeight){
>       // if there is no text overflow ,show the fade out truncator
>       this.renderer.setStyle(this.truncator.nativeElement,'display','block')
>
>     }else{
>     // else (there is a text overflow)
>       this.renderer.setStyle(this.truncator.nativeElement,'display','none')
>
>     }
>   }
>
> }
> ```

Comment: Because your HTML hasn't loaded yet, if you read the lifecycle hook, you'll know that ngAfterViewInit is called after Angular has completely initialized a component's view and ngOnInit comes before that.so just  move the treatement inside the ngAfterViewInint

Comment: Yes and the question would be? If you're declaring the `@ViewChild` properties with option `static: false`, they would only be accessible _after_ they are rendered ergo in `ngAfterViewInit()` hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what's the problem? :)
This is a normal behaviour. `ngOnInit(){}` runs before Angular initializes the component's views and child views. You shouldn't use ngOnInit for this purpose. I suggest you to take a look at [Lifecycle hooks, Angular](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).